# python pydictionary wont import?

Tags: python, pip

When I call pip freeze it lists pydictionary as being an installed module, and when i call pydictionary in terminal, it does stuff but if i try to import PyDictionary into my python, it says the module does not exist?

```
$ pydictionary

results is

Enter words in a string separated by commas: Enter words in a string separated by commas: happy, ever
PyDictionary:
/home/ME/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/bs4/__init__.py:181: UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("lxml"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 11 of the file /home/ME/anaconda3/bin/pydictionary. To get rid of this warning, change code that looks like this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup])

to this:

 BeautifulSoup([your markup], "lxml")

  markup_type=markup_type))
Happy:
Adjective:
enjoying or showing or marked by joy or pleasure
marked by good fortune
eagerly disposed to act or to be of service
well expressed and to the point
Ever:
Adverb:
at any time
at all times; all the time and on every occasion
(intensifier for adjectives
```

and

```
$ pip freeze

...
pycosat==0.6.1
pycparser==2.17
pycrypto==2.6.1
pycurl==7.43.0
PyDictionary==1.5.2
...
```

but

```
$ python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pydictionary
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydictionary'
```

Comment: Tried to import PyDictionary instead ? Case of letters matters in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in the docs: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDictionary

```
from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
dictionary = PyDictionary()

print (dictionary.meaning("indentation"))
```

output:

```
{'Noun': ['a concave cut into a surface or edge (as in a coastline', 'the

 formation of small pits in a surface as a consequence of corrosion', 'th

e space left between the margin and the start of an indented line', 'the

act of cutting into an edge with toothlike notches or angular incisions']

}
```

UPDATE: Based on the discussion in comments, In sublime add a new build system

Tools->build system-> new build systems add

```
{
    "cmd": ["/Users/<user>/anaconda3/bin/python", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Switch build system to this build system and try build.

Comment: Hi, this works in my terminal


$ python
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
>>> dictionary = PyDictionary()



But not when I put it in my code, where "from PyDictionary import PyDictionary" gives me the error    
"File "/home/NAME/Desktop/FOLDER/FOLDER/FOLDER/knock.py", line 2, in <module>
    from PyDictionary import PyDictionary
ImportError: No module named PyDictionary"

Comment: Because you have Anaconda installed. So when you are running `knock.py` the python libraries that it is accessing is different from `python` shell.

Comment: what command are you using to run `/home/NAME/Desktop/FOLDER/FOLDER/FOLDER/knock.py` ??

Comment: Im building it in sublime

Comment: How do you build accesing the normal anaconda library instead of anaconda? I tried changing my build file to "{ "shell_cmd": "/usr/bin/env python3 ${file}", "selector": "source.python", "file_regex": "...*?:([0-9]):?([0-9])", "working_dir": "${file_path}", }"   to avoid this but the issue is the same

Comment: in terminal type `which python` it will give something like `/Users/<user>/anaconda4/bin/python` use this in Sublime.

Comment: How would I use this address in sublime?

Comment: click on Tools->build system-> new build systems add `"shell_cmd": "/Users/<user>/anaconda4/bin/python"`

Comment: add an error statement and see if it fails or not. If it fails then at least its running and build is successful that's why its not printing anything.

Comment: Actually mine is also not working. trying to figure it. give me sometime.

Comment: @user8406345 I have update the answer with what I did to fix the build problem. I tried it and it worked for me. Try it and let me know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem also, so I switched to dictionary. Install it using:

```
pip install dictionary
```